# How to ensure a Promise does not update an outdated page in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, promise

I use Angular 9 and have a component that executes a Promise that eventually comes back with data.

In the meantime, until the Promise got resolved, the user could have already switched the page and the current view is outdated.

One solution I could think of is to store the input of the promise in the caller object and check again inside before applying the data. Is that correct?

```js
this.input = input;
this.manager.doSomething(input).then((value) => {
   if (input == this.input) {
        // add value to current html page
   }
});
```

Is there a common approach to cancel the promise, once someone changes the page or should the UI prevent the user from switching. I come from C++ and therefore this single-threaded environment with Promises is very new to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promises can not be canceled. That is one of the reasons Observables came in. Angular built in http is made on observables. You can just unsubscribe from observable which will cause "cancel". If you want to stay with promises, then yea, save "no longer need to handle" state somewhere. for example in `ngOnDestroy` hook do `this.destroyed = true;` and check in the promise callback whether you need to evaluate the resto of the code.

Comment: Thanks! Would unsubscribing also "cancel" the operation in the background?

Comment: yes, it would be canceled. if it is a http request - you will see "canceled" in the dev tools